# Trying to understand this line of java code

Tags: java, android

```
mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
```

This is some java code for an android app tutorial. I don't understand the what this is doing exactly. I know it's assigning a value to mCallback but what? why is OnHeadlineSelectedListener in parenthesis and then the activity object is right behind it, what the heck?

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package com.vizoplex.my.first.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment {
    OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;

    // The container Activity must implement this interface so the frag can deliver messages
    public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
        /** Called by HeadlinesFragment when a list item is selected */
        public void onArticleSelected(int position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // We need to use a different list item layout for devices older than Honeycomb
        int layout = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 : android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;

        // Create an array adapter for the list view, using the Ipsum headlines array
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), layout, Ipsum.Headlines));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // When in two-pane layout, set the listview to highlight the selected list item
        // (We do this during onStart because at the point the listview is available.)
        if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment) != null) {
            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception.
        try {
            mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Notify the parent activity of selected item
        mCallback.onArticleSelected(position);

        // Set the item as checked to be highlighted when in two-pane layout
        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the tutorial or some surrounding lines? I can tell you that it's casting the object referenced by the variable "activity" to the class OnHeadlineSelectedListener, and then setting that value to the variable mCallback, but that doesn't mean anything to me without context.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I needed to know. I'm new to java and android development. I remember casting variables but I didn't think to apply it to objects too.

Comment: If you prefer, objects are just complex (or simple) variables. You could cast an `int` to a `float`, but also an `Integer` (class that behaves as an integer) to a `Float`. By the way, you should accept one answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is trying to cast that activity to an `OnHeadlineSelectedListener`, probably because this actual activity extends that `Listener`. This way, mCallback acts as a listener with the callback correctly defined.

**Edit**:

There you have:

```
try {
    mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
    throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
            + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
}
```

It's trying to cast `activity` to `OnHeadlineSelectedListener`. If `activity` doesn't implement this Listener, then an exception is thrown. The message is pretty straightforward:

```
activity.toString()+ " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener"
```

Answer (score 2):

That is type casting. 
For example:
You have Animal interface with two methods, run and eat.

```
public interface Animal {
    public String run();
    public String eat(String food);
}
```

And you have class, which implements it, say, Cat class. Cat class has some extra methods, scratch and mew.

```
public class Cat implements Animal{
   public String run(){
     return "Run as a cat";
   }
   public String eat(){
     return "Eat fish";
   }
   public String mew(){
     return "MEW!!!!";
   }
   public String scratch(){
     return "scratch-scratch-scratch";
   }
}
```

Also, you have Dog class, which has bark method.

```
public class Dog implements Animal{
   public String run(){
     return "Run as a dog";
   }
   public String eat(){
     return "Eat meat";
   }
   public String bark(){
     return "BARK!!!!";
   }
}
```

So, very often you need to work with you animal like with some exact animal (dog or cat). But compiler cat not make this casting without your help. So, you have to tell it what exactly you want:

```
public void Show{
  Cat cat = new Cat(); //you have a cat
  Dog dog = new Dog(); //and a dog
  Animal animal = null; //and animal
  dog = (Dog)animal; //and here is where compiler can't convert animal to dog without your help.
  Animal animal2 = cat; //But this casting it can make without your help, as it exactly knows what to do.
}
```

[This one book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071591060) is very usefull to learn Java.  If you are really interested in understanding such things, you should read it. The full explanation of how casting works can be found in this book too.

Answer (score 1):

`activity` is being [casted](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) to an `OnHeadlineSelectedListener` object, which `mCallback` is being assigned to.

Answer (score 1):

I think mCallback object is the subclass of activity object's class. 
So this statement casts the activity object to a more specific mCallback object.

For more information on casting [Click here](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-object-typecasting)

Answer (score 0):

It's casting an activity to be a OnHeadlineSelectedListener. It's assuming that the activity implements OnHeadlineSelectedListener. This is being done so you can directly call methods in the interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener.

Answer (score 0):

I've transitioned out of Java recently, but it looks to me as if that line is *casting* `activity` to the type `OnHeadlineSelectedListener`. Casting makes one type into another, and throws an Exception (of one form or another,) if the types are incompatible.

The syntax is this:

```
variable = (Type) variableOfType2;
```